# How to use Response for Form Array?[ PlayFramework ]

Tags: playframework

Thank you for reading my Question.

How to use response for Form Array ?

## Please read printSystem.scala.html

```
public class Test extends Controller {

    static int form_max_length = 100;   
    static Form<Torque> torqueForm;
    static Torque[] torque = new Torque[form_max_length];
    static int checkData = 0;

    public static Result completeData() {
        torqueForm = form(Torque.class).bindFromRequest();

        for (int checkData=0; checkData<form_max_length; checkData++) {
            if (torque[checkData] != null) {
                checkData++;            
            } else {
                torque[checkData] = torqueForm.get();
                torque[checkData].save();
                break;
            }
        }

        return TODO; 
        }

    public static Result printData() {

        return ok(printSystem.render(torqueForm));

    }
}
```

---

torqueSystem.scala.html

---

```
@main("") {

<form action="/test" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label> Title </label>
        <input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> Contents </label>
        <input type="text" name="contents">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>

}
```

---

printSystem.scala.html

---

```
    @(form: Form[Torque])

    main("") {
        @form.field("id").value()
        @form.field("title").value()
        @form.field("contents").value()
    }
```

---

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell exactly what your problem is but I try to guess. May I present you an alternative? It should work with Play 2.1.x.

Instead of an array you might want to use a Map. It also obtainable as response from the form.

```
public static Result completeData() {
    DynamicForm f = play.data.Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    Map<String, String> formData = f.data();

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : formData.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (key.equals("contents")) {
            yourModel.setSomeData(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want your array you can process it with formData.entrySet().toArray().

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you.i will use this source ^^♥